# Derivative change sign

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

If the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ has an extremum at the point $x$, and $f$ is differentiable in some neighborhood of $x$. Is it right that the derivative changes sign when passing through $x?$

Comment: By extremum do you mean a local minimum or maximum?

Comment: Yes, local minimum or maximum.

Comment: No. See, e.g., Example 3.4 in Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis* [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA36&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: How we can prove that in x=0 we have extremum?

Comment: The function is non-negative and has value $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, I was watching at another example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No!

Consider the following function

$$f(x) := 1 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Every point is an extremum and every point is differentiable with derivative zero.

Answer (score 3):

Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis* usually saves the day for these sorts of questions.

In Example 3.4 there, it is noted the differentiable function
$$
f(x)=\cases{x^4\Bigl(2+\sin{1\over x}\Bigr), &$x \ne 0$\cr 0, &$x=0$}
$$
has an extreme value at $x=0$, but $f'$ does not make a simple change in sign at $x=0$ ($f$ is monotone on no interval containing $0$ as an endpoint).

Comment: Taking the derivative from first principles at $x = 0$, $f'(x) = x^3 (2 + sin(\frac{1}{x}))$; this means that $f'(0^-) = 0^-$ and $f'(0^+) = 0^+$. I understand that they both approach zero, but they do approach from different sides. Sorry if I'm being silly, but could you explain what exactly do you mean by "not a simple change in sign at x = 0"?

Comment: @AshishAhuja  I'm not sure what you are computing, but $f′$ is not what you wrote ($f'(x)=x^2\bigl(4x(2+\sin(1/x))-\cos(1/x)\bigr)$ for $x\ne0$). In every open set with $0$ as one endpoint, $f′$ takes on both positive and negative values.