# Increasing and decreasing at point of extrema

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $a\in\mathbb{R}$ be a point of local minimum of $f$. Then is it always true that at one direction of $a$, the function $f$ is increasing and at the other direction the function $f$ is decreasing?

It is not pretty clear to me from the definition.

Can someone help with this please. Thanks.

Comment: No. "wiggle" $y=x\sin(1/x)$ around $y=x^2$ (or something like this).

Comment: Thanks. But I am sorry. The answer is unclear to me. Can you please elaborate? Thanks again.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616792/derivative-change-sign).

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: It's possible for a continuous function to have a strict local minima at each point of a set that is dense in $\mathbb R$ AND to have a strict local maxima at each point of a set that is dense in $\mathbb R$ AND be such that at none of these strict local extrema is there a one-sided neighborhood in which the function is monotone (i.e. non-decreasing throughout that neighborhood or non-increasing throughout that neighborhood), let alone be increasing on one side and decreasing on the other side in the manner you intend. **(continued)**

Comment: See [*Extrema and nowhere differentiable functions*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-16/issue-4/Extrema-and-nowhere-differentiable-functions/10.1216/RMJ-1986-16-4-661.full) by Posey/Vaughan (1986). Note that the functions in this paper, while continuous, are nowhere (finitely) differentiable, and thus cannot be monotone in any interval (by [a standard result in real analysis](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lebesgue-s-theorem-for-the-differentiability-of-monotone-fun)).

Comment: Yes, Thank you.