# Does the converse of the first derivative test hold for isolated extrema?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity, maxima-minima

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be a critical point of *f*. Let *f* be differentiable on an open interval containing *c*, except possibly at *c*.

Can we say that whenever such a function has an isolated (strict) extremum at *c*, say a maximum, then $\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $f'(x) \gt 0; \ \forall x \in \left( c-\delta, c\right)$ and $f'(x)\lt 0; \ \forall x \in (c,c+\delta)$, basically can we say if *f* has an isolated extremum at *c* then the sign of *f'* changes at *c*? If so, can someone please provide a hint to the proof?

Comment: If $f$ is twice differentiable at $c$ then $f''(c) < 0$, so $f'(c + h) = f''(c)h + o(h)$ is negative for $h > 0$ small, and positive for $h < 0$ small. I'm not sure about the case when we only assume differentiability on an open interval not containing $c$.

Comment: Counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616792/derivative-change-sign